# DynamoDBMapper : How to get all the rows for multiple id's(array) in a single query or scan of DynamoDBMapper

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, web-services, amazon-dynamodb

My DB table consist of multiple rows whose id are unique.

**API(Endpoint) -> get the rows for the id's**
i am passing array of inputs (id1,id2,id3,id4)

```
Question : In DynamoDBMapper, write a single query fetching all the rows for the id's that we passed in.
```

we can use either scan or query.

Appreciate your help.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved in single query call (dynamoDBMapper.SCAN). Example as follow

```
    private List<Activity> getbyIds(List<UUID> Ids) {
            List<Entity> activityEntityList = new ArrayList<Entity>();
            List<AttributeValue> attList = Ids.stream().map(x -> new AttributeValue(x.toString())).collect(Collectors.toList());

            DynamoDBScanExpression dynamoDBScanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression()
                    .withFilterConditionEntry("id", new Condition()
                            .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.IN)
                            .withAttributeValueList(attList));
            PaginatedScanList<Entity> list = dynamoDBMapper.scan(Entity.class, dynamoDBScanExpression);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Scan or Query is not suitable for this transaction.

You should iterate your list and use [GetItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html) to retrieve each item individually, which is the fastest and cheapest way to get the items. You can also use [BatchGetItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html) if you wish to perform concurrent requests.

A Scan would be slow and expensive as it would evaluate every single item in your table. However if you insist on using it, simply scan your table and provide a [ScanFilter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LegacyConditionalParameters.ScanFilter.html) to return your items.

If you used a Query, it would operate in exactly the same way as GetItem anyway. You would have to iterate your list of IDs. i.e. a Query is not at all suitable in this case.